# How to extract strings from rows which have .json like format?

Tags: json, r

I have imported a `.json` file using `library(jsonlite)` `stream_in(file(".json"))`

However, one of the columns still looks as a  `.json` format. 
Im not really sure how proceed in order to extact the columns `ID` and `email` from the `.json` column.

```
  My example:

  date <- as.Date(as.character( c("2015-02-13",
                                    "2015-02-14",
                                    "2015-02-14")))
  ID <- c(1,2,3)
  name <- c("John","Michael","Thomas")
  drinks <- c("Beer","Coffee","Tee")
  consumed <- c(2,5,3)
  john<- "{\"employeID\":\"1\",\"other_details\":{\"email\":\"john@gmx.com\"},\"computer\":\"yes\"}"
  michael<- "{\"employeID\":\"2\",\"other_details\":{\"email\":\"michael@yahoo.com\"},\"computer\":\"yes\"}"
  thomas<- "{\"employeID\":\"3\",\"other_details\":{\"email\":\"thomas@gmail.com\"},\"computer\":\"yes\"}"
  json <- c(john,michael,thomas)
  df <- data.frame(date,ID,name,drinks,consumed,json)
```

Where the data.frame looks like that:

[image]

I would like to get the following format:

```
         date ID    name   drinks    consumed    email       computer
#1 2015-02-13  1    John   Beer        2      john@gmx.com      yes
#2 2015-02-14  2 Michael Coffee        5 michael@yahoo.com       no
#3 2015-02-14  3  Thomas    Tee        3  thomas@gmail.com      yes
```

What I have tried was to was first to use the `library(jsonlite)` again in different variations but it always results in:

```
fromJSON(df$json[1])  

Error: Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.
```

How can I extract these fields properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df$json` is a factor vector while `fromJSON` only accepts a JSON string, URL or file. You can try

```
fromJSON(as.character(df$json[1]))
```

or add `stringsAsFactor=FALSE` when you create `df`.

You do your task, you can try:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  filter(json != "{}") %>%   # Drop rows with json == "{}"
  rowwise() %>%
  do(data.frame(ID = .$ID, jsonlite::fromJSON(.$json), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)) %>% 
  merge(df %>% select(-json), by="ID", all.y=TRUE)
```

Output:

```
  ID employeID             email computer       date    name drinks consumed
1  1         1      john@gmx.com      yes 2015-02-13    John   Beer        2
2  2         2 michael@yahoo.com      yes 2015-02-14 Michael Coffee        5
3  3         3  thomas@gmail.com      yes 2015-02-14  Thomas    Tee        3
```

It can handle cases with `"{}"` in `json` column.

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  rbind(data.frame(date="2015-02-14", ID=4, name="Kitman", 
                   drinks="Chocolate", consumed=1, json="{}"))

df2 %>% 
  filter(json != "{}") %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  do(data.frame(ID = .$ID, jsonlite::fromJSON(.$json), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)) %>% 
  merge(df2 %>% select(-json), by="ID", all.y=TRUE)
```

Output:

```
  ID employeID             email computer       date    name    drinks consumed
1  1         1      john@gmx.com      yes 2015-02-13    John      Beer        2
2  2         2 michael@yahoo.com      yes 2015-02-14 Michael    Coffee        5
3  3         3  thomas@gmail.com      yes 2015-02-14  Thomas       Tee        3
4  4      <NA>              <NA>     <NA> 2015-02-14  Kitman Chocolate        1
```

---

**Outdated:**

```
cbind(
  df %>% select(-json), 
  df$json %>% 
    map(~as.data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(.))) %>% 
    do.call("rbind", .)
)
```

Output:

```
        date ID    name drinks consumed employeID             email computer
1 2015-02-13  1    John   Beer        2         1      john@gmx.com      yes
2 2015-02-14  2 Michael Coffee        5         2 michael@yahoo.com      yes
3 2015-02-14  3  Thomas    Tee        3         3  thomas@gmail.com      yes
```

Comment: Hi @kitman0804, thx for your suggestion  and time. Why doesnt your function work on data frames where column `.json` may contain empty `{}`lists or lists with varying variables?

Comment: `fromJSON("{}")` returns an empty list, and `as.data.frame` an empty list returns a data.frame with 0 rows and 0 columns. So, the number of rows of the 2nd argument is not the same as the 1st one's if you have `"{}"` in some rows, and thus cause an error in `cbind` step.

Comment: @Googme I have updated my answer, which is able to handle empty `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

First, try:

```
ndjson::stream_in("filename.json")
```

The `ndjson` package is faster than `jsonlite` and was built for flattening (it's very task-specific and not as swiss-army-knife-ish as the highly useful `jsonlite` pkg).

Or, we can keep the tidyverse idioms all the way through:

```
library(tidyverse)

map_df(df$json, ~jsonlite::fromJSON(as.character(.))) %>% 
  bind_cols(select(df, -json)) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.list, as.character) %>% 
  select(ID, name, drinks, consumed, everything())
## # A tibble: 3 × 8
##      ID    name drinks consumed computer employeID other_details.email       date
##   <dbl>   <chr>  <chr>    <dbl>    <chr>     <chr>               <chr>     <date>
## 1     1    John   Beer        2      yes         1        john@gmx.com 2015-02-13
## 2     2 Michael Coffee        5      yes         2   michael@yahoo.com 2015-02-14
## 3     3  Thomas    Tee        3      yes         3    thomas@gmail.com 2015-02-14
```

And, you get your character columns.

Comment: Hi @hrbrmstr, thank you for your time spending. Does `ndjson` has some like `stream_in(file(".json"))` to import ` .json` files?

Comment: Well, that would be the `nsjson::stream_in("filename.json")` example I gave right at the beginning. You don't need to make a connection, you just give it a filename.

Comment: No. The larger example was if you're not going to use `ndjson`. You shouldn't need to do anything but `ndjson::stream_in("filename.json")`

Comment: I meant here `map_df(df$json, ~jsonlite::fromJSON(as.character(.)))` , I thouht that was possible as well `map_df(df$json, ~nsjson::fromJSON(as.character(.)))`

Comment: shld be `ndjson` (I mis-typed it once) and that wld need to be `flatten` vs `stream_in()`. Refresh the page .

Comment: Thx for clarification. However, I get always `Error  in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : incompatible sizes (1 != 9) ` when using that on the original table which is almost identical. But still txh a lot!